# Is there any option for time out other than plug-in to abort a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a declarative pipeline job which I need to abort it in a specific timeframe, (say 1 hour) if the mentioned agent is not taken the job. Timeout in global level or stage level is working. But the thing is pipeline needs to be aborted if the agent takes more than expected time. If my job gets aborted then the queued jobs will get triggered. My job is blocking the next jobs. Any inputs is appreciated.